# Regex <img > Tag parsing with src, width, height

Tags: java, android, html, regex

You may react to this saying that H**TML Parsing using regex is a totally bad idea**, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for example, and you are right.

But in my case, the following html node is created by our own server so we know that it will always look like this, and as the regex will be in a **mobile android library**, I don't want to use a library like Jsoup.

**What I want to parse**: `<img src="myurl.jpg" width="12" height="32">`

**What should be parsed**:

- match a regular img tag, and group the src attribute value: `<img[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>`
- width and height attribute values: `(width|height)\s*=\s*['"]([^'"]*)['"]*`

So the first regex will have a #1 group with the img url, and the second regex will have two matches with subgroups of their values.

**How can I merge both?**

Desired output:

- img url
- width value
- height value

Comment: You want to extract values from the input string?. What is the expected output?

Comment: do you want **[this](https://regex101.com/r/tZ0xZ2/1)** ?

Comment: Or [`"(?:<img\\b|(?!^)\\G)[^>]*?\\b(src|width|height)="([^"]*)"`](https://regex101.com/r/tD4gW4/2)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew write it as answer..

Comment: "the following html node is created by our own server" so change the server to return JSON instead. The server is always the one meant to do the heavy lifting, never the mobile device.

Comment: @rock321987: Yours is simpler, and maybe is quite enough for OP. Also, I am not sure what exact output is necessary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it may be simpler, but not what OP wants..modification in yours will be much easier..mine is too restrictive..the output is still not clear though

Comment: I've udpate the post I think @rock321987 already got the answer

Comment: @HugoGresse: The main point is whether the attributes can be "shuffled" or not, do they always come in the same order?

Comment: I will still go with @WiktorStribiżew solution as it can be used in much broader domain

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if we want to maximise html compatibily, the attribute don't have orders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match any `img` tag with `src`, `height` and `width` attributes that can come in any order and that are in fact optional, you can use

```
"(<img\\b|(?!^)\\G)[^>]*?\\b(src|width|height)=([\"']?)([^>]*?)\\3"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aL8hG6/1) and an [IDEONE Java demo](http://ideone.com/BLAE97):

```
String s = "<img height=\"132\" src=\"NEW_myurl.jpg\" width=\"112\"><link src=\"/test/test.css\"/><img src=\"myurl.jpg\" width=\"12\" height=\"32\">";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<img\\b|(?!^)\\G)[^>]*?\\b(src|width|height)=([\"']?)([^\"]*)\\3");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    if (!matcher.group(1).isEmpty()) { // We have a new IMG tag
        System.out.println("\n--- NEW MATCH ---");  
    }
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2) + ": " + matcher.group(4));
}
```

The regex details:

- `(<img\\b|(?!^)\\G)` - the initial boundary matching the `<img>` tag start or the end of the previous successful match
- `[^>]*?` - match any optional attributes we are not interested in (0+ characters other than `>` so as to stay inside the tag) 
  -`\\b(src|width|height)=` - a whole word `src=`, `width=` or `height=`
- `([\"']?)` - a technical 3rd group to check the attribute value delimiter
- `([^>]*?)` - Group 4  containing the attribute value (0+ characters other than a `>` as few as possible up to the first
- `\\3` - attribute value delimiter matched with the Group 3 (**NOTE** if a delimiter may be empty, add `(?=\\s|/?>)` at the end of the pattern)

The logic:

- Match the start of `img` tag
- Then, match everything that is inside, but only capture the attributes we need
- Since we are going to have multiple matches, not groups, we need to find a boundary for each new `img` tag. This is done by checking if the first group is not empty (`if (!matcher.group(1).isEmpty())`)
- All there remains to do is to add a list for keeping matches.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine the both the things here is the answer.

```
<img\s+src="([^"]+)"\s+width="([^"]+)"\s+height="([^"]+)"
```

sample I tested

```
<img src="rakesh.jpg" width="25" height="45">
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You may want this :</strike>

```
"(?i)(src|width|height)=\"(.*?)\""
```

---

**Update:**

I misunderstood your question, you need something like :

```
"(?i)<img\\s+src=\"(.*?)\"\\s+width=\"(.*?)\"\\s+height=\"(.*?)\">"
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gM1oY7/2)

---

**Update 2**

The regex below will capture the `img` tag attributes in any order:

```
"(?i)(?><img\\s+)src=\"(.*?)\"|width=\"(.*?)\"|height=\"(.*?)\">"
```

[Regex101 Demo v2](https://regex101.com/r/gM1oY7/6)

Comment: This will match any `src`, `height` and `width` attributes in the HTML code.

Comment: Yes, it does, so the OP knows which value is matching, `width` vs `height` for example, and the order of the tags doesn't matter, it can be a different `img` tag with reordered attributes and it still works.

Comment: but it will not validate the <img> tag

Comment: If the attributes can come in different order, my regex is the right solution.

Comment: @PedroLobito: Read the whole question. However, it did not help me understand all of it. The main point is that only `img` tags should be matched.

Comment: [I would not use dot matching pattern here](https://regex101.com/r/bR5fZ9/1). Maybe it is not an issue here, but just best practice.

Comment: As you said, it shouldn't make any difference here, once gain, thanks for the comments :)

Comment: The regex seems to not work on RegExr or Regex101.com, can you update it?

Comment: @HugoGresse Are you sure you're seeing my regex ?  https://regex101.com/r/gM1oY7/2

Comment: my bad, difference between java regex and javascript, thanks. What can you do if the attributes order change?

Comment: I think the original answer was just missing the <img> tag check, but with them I have the correct attribute information (no order)

Comment: @HugoGresse "***Wiktor still the answer***" as long as you got your answer I'm happy with it ;)