# Regular expression for extracting src

Tags: regex

I want to pull out the string after src like for the following two samples as:

1. Images/17/0000894189/0000894189-17-005831/image00003.jpg
2. Images/17/0000894189/0000894189-17-005831/image0.jpg

```html
<div style="TEXT-ALIGN: center"><img src="Images/17/0000894189/0000894189-17-005831/image00003.jpg"></div>

<div style="TEXT-ALIGN: justify"><iMg style="HEIGHT: 63px; WIDTH: 289px" src="Images/17/0000894189/0000894189-17-005831/image0.jpg"></div>
```

Could you please suggest regular expression which can give me this value? The position of src attribute in the img tag can vary.

Comment: I would suggest you use proper library to get the attribute. Unsure what's the programming language you are using though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex <img > Tag parsing with src, width, height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978966/regex-img-tag-parsing-with-src-width-height)

Comment: Don't use a regex to parse html.  What if you have a newline in your tag?

Comment: Using C# programming language. You're right there could be newline in the tag, what is other way you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on where you use the regex, but something like

```
.*src="(\([^"]*\)".*
```

should give you the path you're looking for in `sed`, eg

```
sed -n '/img src/s#src="(\([^"]*\)"#\1#gp' inputfile
```

Comment: i think it's .*src="([^"]*)".*

Comment: This gives only first match, if there are multiple matches then how those will be returned?